# c# Bind executable and parameter in one exe

Tags: c#, xml, binding, resources, exe

i want to create a executable file that ask for a "exe file" and a "xml file" and create ONLY ONE executable file, so when the user runs it is calls the selected "exe file" with the parameters of "xml file" but i want the final user to see only ONE file

Comment: i think it is not possible, you can store the xml data in the application memory itself, or store in  DB and get it

Comment: I think this is possible, but might require some deep magic to unpack a PE file, add parameters as resources, patch or replace the entry point, and fix the PE header. And it will not work if the file is signed.

Comment: i will program the executor file, i just want another program to join executor and parameters